# Trying to mix data from a CSV and a hashtable to make a variable

Tags: powershell, csv, variables, hashtable, powershell-5.0

I stopped over at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), asking how I could streamline a script and was advised to use a **hashtable** as it would clean up the code.  I was given a very basic example but it wasn't *plug-and-play*.  I've worked up some basic code but it's not doing what I think it should.  Knowing the Code Review folks aren't there for support like this, here i am, looking for help with combining a variable from a CSV and a hashtable.  I'll leave sample data from my CSV and the Powershell code below.

**Sample CSV:**

```
Student First Name,I,Student Last Name,Other ID,Stu Access Login,Student's School Email,School,Grad Year
Johosofat,L,Smith,999999,smithjoh000,smithjoh000@mydomain.org,30,2017
Tome,M,Smith,999998,smithtom000,smithtom000@mydomain.org,40,2021
```

**Sample Powershell:**

```
# Testing simple hash table
$SchoolCodes = @{
        20 = "Exeter Township Senior High"
        30 = "Exeter Township Junior High"
        40 = "Lorane Elementary School"
        50 = "Jacksonwald ES"
        70 = "Reiffton School"
        90 = "Owatin Creek Elementary School"
}

# CSV file being imported.
$CsvFile = "$env:USERPROFILE\Downloads\SampleData.csv"

# Import the contents of the CSV file.
$Users = Import-Csv -Path "$CsvFile"

# Loop through each line of the CSV, creating variables for each field.
ForEach ($User in $Users) {
    # Creating the basic variables.
    $FirstName = $User.'Student First Name'
    $MiddleInitial = $User.'I'
    $LastName = $User.'Student Last Name'
    $ADUserName = $User.'Stu Access Login'
    $StudentID = $User.'Other ID'
    $GradYear = $User.'Grad Year'
    $CapFInitial = $FirstName.substring(0,1).ToUpper()
    $MInitial = $MiddleInitial.substring(0,1).ToLower()
    $LInitial = $LastName.substring(0,1).ToLower()
    $Password = "$CapFInitial$MInitial$LInitial" + "#" + "$StudentID"
    $SchoolCode = $SchoolCodes[$User.School]


    If (-Not(Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $ADUserName})) {
        Try {
            # Create user.
            New-ADUser `
                -Name "$FirstName $LastName" `
                -SamAccountName "$ADUserName" `
                -GivenName "$FirstName" `
                -Initials "$MiddleInitial" `
                -Surname "$LastName" `
                -DisplayName "$FirstName $MiddleInitial. $LastName" `
                -UserPrincipalName "$ADUserName@mydomain.k12.pa.us" `
                -EmailAddress "$ADUserName@mydomain.k12.pa.us" `
                -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force) `
                -Enabled $false `
                -PasswordNeverExpires $true `
                -CannotChangePassword $true `
                -Path "OU=$GradYear,OU=Students,OU=$SchoolCode,OU=accounts,DC=academic,DC=mydomain,DC=k12,DC=pa,DC=us" `
                -WhatIf
        }

        Catch {
            Write-Error "[ERROR] Can't create user [$($ADUserName)] : $_"
        }
    }
}
```

**My issue:**
The script ultimately errors out because of the `$SchoolCode` variable being set to **null**, I think.  I'm wanting the script to find the number (code) from the **school** field in the CSV and match that to the name which ends up being an OU in AD - where the User Object will get created.  Basically, the code tries to create the User Object in `"CN=Tome Smith,OU=2021,OU=Students,OU=,OU=accounts,DC=academic,DC=exeter,DC=k12,DC=pa,DC=us"` which shows the `$SchoolCode` variable is either blank or otherwise not getting set correctly.

As I mentioned in a comment, we're thinking of adding other static data to the hashtable as a (nested?) hashtable.  Here's an example of what we're thinking about.  As time goes by, the list of AD groups may grow.

**Example of the *nested* hashtable:**

```
$SchoolCodes = @{
    20 = @{
        Name = "Exeter Township Senior High"
        ADGroup1 = "Students"
        ADGroup2 = "Secondary Students"
    }
    30 = @{
        Name = "Exeter Township Junior High"
        ADGroup1 = "Students"
        ADGroup2 = "Secondary Students"
    }
    40 = @{
        Name = "Lorane Elementary School"
        ADGroup1 = "Students"
        ADGroup2 = "K4 Students"
    }
    50 = @{
        Name = "Jacksonwald ES"
        ADGroup1 = "Students"
        ADGroup2 = "K4 Students"
    }
    70 = @{
        Name = "Reiffton School"
        ADGroup1 = "Students"
        ADGroup2 = "Secondary Students"
    }
    90 = @{
        Name = "Owatin Creek Elementary School"
        ADGroup1 = "Students"
        ADGroup2 = "K4 Students"
    }
}
```

I'm scouring the web and trying to get a better understanding of hashtables.  If I can wrap my head around it, nesting them would be my next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're re-using the data, it's not important to turn it into a hashtable.  Also, the error is in accessing the `$SchoolCodes` value.  For some reason, the accessor isn't working with a `[String]`, but does work when you cast to an `[Int]`

Sample dataset:

```
Student First Name,I,Student Last Name,Other ID,Stu Access Login,Student's School Email,School,Grad Year
Johosofat,L,Smith,999999,smithjoh000,smithjoh000@mydomain.org,30,2017
Tome,M,Smith,999998,smithtom000,smithtom000@mydomain.org,40,2021
```

Code:

```
#requires -Version 3
$SchoolCodes = @{
    20 = "Exeter Township Senior High"
    30 = "Exeter Township Junior High"
    40 = "Lorane Elementary School"
    50 = "Jacksonwald ES"
    70 = "Reiffton School"
    90 = "Owatin Creek Elementary School"
}

# CSV file being imported.
$CsvFile = "$env:USERPROFILE\Downloads\SampleData.csv"

# Import the contents of the CSV file.
$Users = Import-Csv -Path "$CsvFile"

# Loop through each line of the CSV, creating variables for each field.
ForEach ($User in $Users)
{
    [String]$LoginName = $User.'Stu Access Login'
    If (-not (Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $LoginName}))
    {
        $FirstName = $User.'Student First Name'
        $LastName = $User.'Student Last Name'

        $Params = @{
            Name = "$FirstName $LastName"
            SamAccountName = $LoginName
            GivenName = $FirstName
            Initials = $User.I
            Surname = $LastName
            DisplayName = "$FirstName $($User.I) $LastName"
            UserPrincipalName = "$LoginName@mydomain.k12.pa.us"
            EmailAddress = "$LoginName@mydomain.k12.pa.us"
            AccountPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String (
                '{0}{1}{2}#{3}' -f @(
                    $FirstName[0].ToString().ToUpper(),
                    $User.I[0].ToString().ToLower(),
                    $LastName[0].ToString().ToLower(),
                    $User.'Other ID')) -AsPlainText -Force
            Enabled = $False
            PasswordNeverExpires = $True
            CannotChangePassword = $True
            Path = 'OU={0},OU=Students,OU={1},OU=accounts,DC=academic,DC=mydomain,DC=k12,DC=pa,DC=us' -f @(
                $User.'Grad Year',
                $SchoolCodes[[Int]$User.School])
            WhatIf = $True
        }

        Try {New-ADUser @Params}
        Catch {Write-Error "[ERROR] Can't create user [$LoginName] : $_"}
    }
}
```

Comment: That script will be reused every time an AD account needs to be created.  Basically, as students come into the district.  Ultimately, I'd like to add more _static_ data to that hashtable as (possibly) nested hashtables.

Comment: @RKillcrazy The script gets re-used, sure, but the hashtables do not, which is where they are beneficial.  Anyways, the bug in your code was with the `$SchoolCodes` accessor being a String and it wanted an Int.  Try defining your hashtable like `'20' = 'schoolname'` and see if that will fix your specific issue.

Comment: Dropping quotes around the school codes fixed my code immediately; thanks for that!  Your code, while looking more _elegant_ than mine, had errors: `Get-ADUser : Invalid type 'System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject'.` That said, I'd like to know more about your code if at all possible.  For one, I see you using `{0}{1}` (substitutions?) for the `AccountPassword` and `Path` arguments.  What is the proper name for that sort of thing?

Comment: @RKillcrazy That's weird.  Put `[String]` in front of `$User`.  That's called the format operator, it works with `-f @(array)`

Comment: Where abouts should `[String]` go?  I see a few instances of `$User` in your code and  I've tested it in several of those locations and am still seeing errors.

Comment: @RKillcrazy I've adjusted my example.

Comment: Your adjusted code gives the following error:  
`Method invocation failed because [System.Char] does not contain a method named 'ToUpper'.`

Comment: @RKillcrazy Bizarre that it's treating that as a `[Char]`.  Append `.ToString().ToUpper()`

Comment: I tweaked the `AccountPassword` parameter as seen below and the errors cleared.

`AccountPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String ('{0}{1}{2}#{3}' -f @($FirstName[0].ToString().ToUpper(),$User.I[0].ToString().ToLower(),$LastName[0].ToString().ToLower(),$User.'Other ID')) -AsPlainText -Force`