# Splatting and Formatting Operator Work Elsewhere

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I've been asked to tweak a script I was working on a while ago.  I got help for it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46941382/).  In the script, I use splatting and the format operator.  It works further up the script but fails down low.  I broke out a much smaller sample which shows the failure.  If you need to see the full script, I can provide it.  Been looking at the code for a while and I have to be missing something simple.

```
# Creating the Event Log and Source if it doesn't already exist.
# You should only have to create the log/source once and it needs to be done with an elevated prompt.
$EventLogFile = Get-EventLog -list | Where-Object {$_.LogDisplayName -eq "AD User Creation Script"} 
If (-Not $EventLogFile) {
    New-EventLog -LogName "AD User Creation Script" -Source "User Creation"
    New-EventLog -LogName "AD User Creation Script" -Source "Enable Existing User"
    New-EventLog -LogName "AD User Creation Script" -Source "Flush Groups"
    New-EventLog -LogName "AD User Creation Script" -Source "Change OU"
    New-EventLog -LogName "AD User Creation Script" -Source "Populate Groups"
}

# Nested hash table for school codes.
$SchoolCodes = @{
    "20" = @{
        Name = "Exeter Township Senior High"
        ADGroup1 = "Students"
        ADGroup2 = "Secondary Students"
    }
    "30" = @{
        Name = "Exeter Township Junior High"
        ADGroup1 = "Students"
        ADGroup2 = "Secondary Students"
    }
    "40" = @{
        Name = "Lorane Elementary School"
        ADGroup1 = "Students"
        ADGroup2 = "K4 Students"
    }
    "50" = @{
        Name = "Jacksonwald ES"
        ADGroup1 = "Students"
        ADGroup2 = "K4 Students"
    }
    "70" = @{
        Name = "Reiffton School"
        ADGroup1 = "Students"
        ADGroup2 = "Secondary Students"
    }
    "90" = @{
        Name = "Owatin Creek Elementary School"
        ADGroup1 = "Students"
        ADGroup2 = "K4 Students"
    }
} # End hash table


# CSV file being imported.
$CsvFile = "$env:USERPROFILE\Downloads\SampleData.csv"

# Import the contents of the CSV file.
$Users = Import-Csv -Path "$CsvFile"

# Loop through each line of the CSV, creating variables for each field.
ForEach ($User in $Users) {
    [String]$LoginName = $User.'Stu Access Login'
    If (-Not (Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $LoginName})) {
        $FirstName = $User.'Student First Name'
        $LastName = $User.'Student Last Name'
        # The following is an example of SPLATTING.  A couple of the parameters (AccountPassword and Path) also use the FORMAT OPERATOR.
        $ADUserParams = @{
            Name = "$FirstName $LastName"
            SamAccountName = $LoginName
            GivenName = $FirstName
            Initials = $User.'I'
            Surname = $LastName
            DisplayName = "$FirstName $($User.'I') $LastName"
            UserPrincipalName = "$LoginName@academic.exeter.k12.pa.us"
            EmailAddress = "$LoginName@myexeter.org"
            Company = "$LoginName@myexeter.org"
            EmployeeID = $User.'Other ID'
            AccountPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String (
                '{0}{1}{2}#{3}' -f @(
                    $FirstName[0].ToString().ToUpper(),
                    $User.I[0].ToString().ToLower(),
                    $LastName[0].ToString().ToLower(),
                    $User.'Other ID')) -AsPlainText -Force
            Enabled = $True
            PasswordNeverExpires = $True
            CannotChangePassword = $True
            Path = 'OU={0},OU=Students,OU={1},OU=accounts,DC=academic,DC=exeter,DC=k12,DC=pa,DC=us' -f @(
                $User.'Grad Year',
                $SchoolCodes[$User.School].Name)
            WhatIf = $False
        } # End ADUserParams

        Try {
            # Create new user.
            New-ADUser @ADUserParams -Verbose -ErrorAction Stop
        }

        Catch {
            # If there's an error, write error to event the log.
            Write-EventLog -LogName "AD User Creation Script" -Source "User Creation" -EntryType Warning -EventId 1 -Message "Something went wrong with the creation of a new user, [$LoginName] : $_"
        }

        Try {
            # Add user to groups.
            Get-ADUser -Identity $LoginName | Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -MemberOf $SchoolCodes[$User.School].ADGroup1, $SchoolCodes[$User.School].ADGroup2 -Verbose -ErrorAction Stop
        }

        Catch {
            # If there's an error, write error to event the log.
            Write-EventLog -LogName "AD User Creation Script" -Source "Populate Groups" -EntryType Warning -EventId 2 -Message "Something went wrong with adding [$LoginName] to groups : $_"
        }

    } # End If

    # If the account already exists, it will likely be disabled.  The following will enable it and add it to the correct groups.
    Else {

        Try {
            # Enable the account if it already exists.
            Enable-ADAccount -Identity $LoginName -Confirm:$False -Verbose -ErrorAction Stop
        }

        Catch {
            # If there's an error, write error to event the log.
            Write-EventLog -LogName "AD User Creation Script" -Source "Enable Existing User" -EntryType Warning -EventId 3 -Message "Something went wrong with the enabling of the existing user, [$LoginName] : $_"
        }

        Try {
            # Move user to the correct OU.
            $MoveADObjectParams = @{
                Identity = $LoginName
                TargetPath = 'OU={0},OU=Students,OU={1},OU=accounts,DC=academic,DC=exeter,DC=k12,DC=pa,DC=us' -f @(
                    $User.'Grad Year',
                    $SchoolCodes[$User.School].Name)
            } # End MoveADObjectParams

            Move-ADObject @MoveADObjectParams -Verbose -ErrorAction Stop
        }

        Catch {
            # If there's an error, write error to event the log.
            Write-EventLog -LogName "AD User Creation Script" -Source "Change OU" -EntryType Warning -EventId 4 -Message "Something went wrong with moving the user, $LoginName, to another OU : $_"
        }

        Try {
            # Remove user from all groups except for Domain Users.
            $ExcessGroups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $LoginName | Where-Object {$_.Name -ne "Domain Users"}
            Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $LoginName -MemberOf $ExcessGroups -Verbose -Confirm:$False
        }

        Catch {
            # If there's an error, write error to event the log.
            Write-EventLog -LogName "AD User Creation Script" -Source "Flush Groups" -EntryType Warning -EventId 5 -Message "Something went wrong with adding [$LoginName] to groups : $_"
        }

        Try {
            # Add user to groups.
            Get-ADUser -Identity $LoginName | Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -MemberOf $SchoolCodes[$User.School].ADGroup1, $SchoolCodes[$User.School].ADGroup2 -Verbose -ErrorAction Stop
        }

        Catch {
            # If there's an error, write error to event the log.
            Write-EventLog -LogName "AD User Creation Script" -Source "Populate Groups" -EntryType Warning -EventId 2 -Message "Something went wrong with adding [$LoginName] to groups : $_"
        }

    } # End Else 

} # End ForEach
```

The error I see is below.  It looks like it's not seeing the correct user but the object is in AD:

```
Move-ADObject : Cannot find an object with identity: 'sicklsen000' under:
'DC=academic,DC=exeter,DC=k12,DC=pa,DC=us'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Move-ADObject @MoveADObjectParams -Verbose
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (sicklsen000:ADObject) [Move-ADObject], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.MoveADObject
```

What's strange is it's getting the correct info as near as I can tell:

```
PS C:\Users\User:> $MoveADObjectParams

Name       Value
----       -----
TargetPath OU=2018,OU=Students,OU=Exeter Township Senior High,OU=accounts,DC=academic,DC=exeter,DC=k12,DC=pa,DC=us
Identity   sicklsen000
```

My test script is using data for 3 users.  They all exist.  Here's an example:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-ADUser sicklsen000 | Select-Object SamAccountName, DistinguishedName

SamAccountName DistinguishedName                                                                                                        
-------------- -----------------                                                                                                        
sicklsen000    CN=Seneca Sickler,OU=2018,OU=Students,OU=Exeter Township Senior High,OU=accounts,DC=academic,DC=exeter,DC=k12,DC=pa,DC=us
```

Comment: Looks like there may be some code missing from your sample. Probably a `foreach($user in $users){` loop.

Comment: The error pretty clearly states that it can't find the user. Verify that 'sicklsen000' is a valid user in the academic.exeter.k12.pa.us domain.

Comment: Think the issue is with the `-Identity` parameter for `Move-Object`.  Evidently, it requires the **DistinguishedName**, not **SamAccountName**.  I need to figure out a clean way of going about that though.

Answer (score 0):

Think I'm getting closer, as far as the error goes.  As I mentioned earlier, the `-Identity` parameter requires **DistinguishedName** property and I was giving it the **SamAccountName** property.

Below, is the code I changed.  I no longer see the error, so that's good.

```
# Move user to the correct OU.
            $LoginNameDN = (Get-ADUser -Identity $LoginName).DistinguishedName
            $MoveADObjectParams = @{
                Identity = "$LoginNameDN"
                TargetPath = 'OU={0},OU=Students,OU={1},OU=accounts,DC=academic,DC=exeter,DC=k12,DC=pa,DC=us' -f @(
                    $User.'Grad Year',
                    $SchoolCodes[$User.School].Name)
            } # End MoveADObjectParams

            Move-ADObject @MoveADObjectParams -Verbose -ErrorAction Stop
        }
```